# How to create a PostgreSQL db schema with column "time" in milliseconds format, like "2020-05-29 19:34:00.789"?

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

How to create a PostgreSQL schema with column "time"  in milliseconds format, like "2020-05-29 19:34:00.789"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, columns (and most data entities in general) don’t have a “format”. They store raw data and it’s up to the client using the data to format it.

The data type that will store millisecond granularity timestamp is:

```
timestamp(3)
```